# WCF service is too busy

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-503

I have a WCF service that worked fine until a "service-window" had elapsed and now I can figure out what is wrong. I can from machine A, browse to the service http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Service/Service.svc and http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/Service/Service.svc?wsdl it work fine. BUT when I'm trying to use the service it don't. To eliminate everything, I have been testing with the WCF Test Client provided by Visual Studio.

When I trying to add the service connection to the Testing tool I get a "Service located at x is too busy" and "(503) Server Unavailable" error. But if I use the same test client directly on the WCF Server everything works.

The service haven't been updated or change since it worked so there isn't anything wrong with the code.

There is some nasty firewalls or something like that between these machines but since the svc file is accessible I get confused.

I don't know where to look for more clues, need help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your service? When you run the client, does it hit the service contract at all?

Comment: The IIS server on which wcf service is deployed, try to check the ApplicationPool it uses and try to restart it to see if this issue gets resolved.  Sometimes if the app pool is not started then you will get 503 exception.  Give it a try.

Comment: I have restarted the apppool several times, it is working.

Comment: The service code isn't hit at all when it isn't working. I can't even add the connection, so haven’t been able to call any functions. If I can browse the service isn't that enough to call it?